# Installing External Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension and install it as part of a larger desktop software install. This is on Windows XP/Vista/7 etc. I've used the method described [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html) and it works.

However, the extension is installed in a disabled state. The user has to explicitly enable it from the Chrome menu (the user has 3 chances to do that before the menu badge disappears) or from the extensions page. Enabling the extension brings up a prompt in which Chrome informs the user of the permissions the extension is requesting and asks the user to reject or accept the extension.

I understand that Google wants to ensure that users have a chance to reject external extensions. I also understand that Google prefers installs via its Web Store (for various logistical reasons, that is not a preferred option for this app). In fact, our application   specifically asks the user for permission before installing the extension.

My issue is that the member has to affirmatively ask for the extension to be enabled before the permissions dialog comes up. Is there any programmatic/command line way to get Chrome to bring the permissions dialog up? The user still has the choice of rejecting the extension, but I would like to present the user with this choice, rather than relying on him/her to try and enable the extension later.

[ I realize that editing the Chrome Preferences file in the installation script will install the extension without any user intervention, but I don't want to do that.]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to [trigger an install from a webpage](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation). Have your installer open chrome with a small webpage that brings up this dialog to the user.